# How to make Docker work on Debian Stretch

Tags: docker, debian

Docker provides .deb files for docker:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo delian-stretch main
```

However, these don't work on Debian Stretch (AMD64) because the kernel does not support the AUFS file system. Switching to the overlay file system leads for me to permission problems in the `/var/lib/docker/overlay` hierarchy (even when root).

I switched to the overlay file system by starting the docker daemon with `--storage-driver overlay` -- this was suggested as a fix in some comments on the Debian bug tracker.

So, what does work?

Comment: Did you try to follow the official guide?: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/#debian-wheezy-stable-7-x-64-bit

Comment: Yes. I now believe the problem is related to a Linux kernel issue:  https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20950. It worked again after booting into an older 4.4.0 kernel.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thank you for the link.